GPIO edge Interrupt not working on STM32G491RET
I am trying to implement a digital waveform capture using an external interrupt on a GPIO.
Here is the test code logic :

Enable a GPIO as output (PA5) and toggle it at 20Hz
Enable another GPIO as input (PC14) with no pullup/pulldown
SYSCFG enabled and EXTI3 is attached to PC14 pin
enable rising edge and falling edge interrupt for EXTI - 14
the IRQHandlerlooks for GPIO_IDR to know if it was a falling edge or rising edge
calculate the period and frequency of the waveform using DWT time stamps

Hardware :

STM32G491ret6 configured for 168MHz
A jumper wire connected between PA5 and PC14

Here is the code :
#include "stm32g491xx.h"

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void) {
    if (EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 14)) {
        uint32_t current_time = DWT->CYCCNT;

        if (GPIOC->IDR & (1 << 14)) {
            // Rising edge detected
            rise++;// = current_time;
        } else {
            // Falling edge detected
            fall++;// = current_time;
        }

        EXTI->PR1 |= (1 << 14); // Clear interrupt flag
    }
}


void DWT_Init(void) {
    CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk; // Enable TRC
    DWT->CYCCNT = 0; // Reset the cycle counter
    DWT->CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk; // Enable the cycle counter
}


void config_interrupt(void)
{

    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOCEN; // Enable GPIOC clock

    GPIOC->MODER &= ~(3 << 28); // PC14 as input
    GPIOC->PUPDR &= ~(3 << 28); // PC14 no pull-up/pull-down
    
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN; // Enable SYSCFG clock
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] &= ~(0xf << 8);
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[3] |= (2 << 8); // Attach EXTI to PC14

    EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1 << 14); // Rising edge trigger
    EXTI->FTSR1 |= (1 << 14); // Falling edge trigger

    EXTI->IMR1 |= (1 << 14); // Enable EXTI line 14

    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 1);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
}

int main(void) {

    clock_conf(); 
    DWT_Init();
    config_interrupt(); 

    while (1) {
        // Calculate the time difference in microseconds
        // time_difference_us = (float)pulse_width / (168000000 / 1000000);
        // Use the time difference as needed
    }
}

I was debugging using Cortex-Debug on VSCode with live watch, updating watch variables at 4Hz. I see no change in the rise and fall counters. Also, the PA5 is connected to LED so I can see the LED toggling - PA5 is all good to toggle.
However, I plugged the PC14 into an onboard button pin (which is PC13) to see if it is detecting the edges while pressing the button. What happens is that I have to keep pressing the button for ~0.5 seconds to see an increase in the rise counter. So to check, when I reduced the pin toggling rate from 20Hz to say 2Hz, it started showing an increase in the counters.
Here is the plan eventually, I have a rotary encoder that gives a PWM output @120Hz. I want to get RPM and position from the encoder. So I need to detect rising and falling edges much faster to get rpm and position within microseconds while other part of the code runs. But my code doesn't seem to be working above 2Hz wave detection.
Can anyone give me insights on what I might be doing wrong?
Let me know if more info is needed...
Thanks!
